# Set default timezone in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am trying to set default time-zone so that app will work on that timezone not from local.
I tried using the Moment for this like:

> moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");

This is not working for me. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: As per moment.js it should work, what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: I am expecting that moment() will give me time according to default timezone. Right now time is same before and after applying set default function.

Comment: When I select date from datepicker I want a date from set timezone